# Wine selection when dining on horse meat?

Tags: wine

I know there is a lot of received wisdom about what sorts of wines to pair with, say, beef or fish or chicken, though I couldn't quote any of it off the top of my own head, as I am the furthest thing from a gourmand in this world. Nevertheless, I am wondering: are there the same kind of "traditional" or "standard" wine recommendations for pairing with horse meat, and what are they?

Comment: Since my question quickly got a downvote, I'll clarify my own thinking here: I view the wine selection for the meal as "ingredient selection and use." But if I've misinterpreted the FAQ and this is actually off-topic here, I will happily remove the question posthaste.

Comment: I think the question is absolutely on topic. Anyway, downvoting without explaining what is wrong is just plain useless.

Comment: You're not going to find this in the corner store and it is not cheap, but it is probably the best thing with horse -http://www.avenuedesvins.fr/vin_effervescent-cremant---bouvet-ladubay-tresor-rose-brut_505.php      Now you need to decide if the horsemeat is worth the effort!

Comment: I guess you mean [gourmet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gourmet), not [gourmand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gourmand)?

Comment: @Stephie, thank you, but I actually meant gourmand, as I wrote. Quoting your own link: "A gourmand is a person who takes great pleasure and interest in consuming good food and drink." That is *exactly* what I am not; I partake in the same handful of largely flavorless foods every day of my life, as I do not care for the taste of the vast majority of foodstuffs. (Now, I'm also not a gourmet, but I intended to emphasize the stronger point that the topic I'm asking about is truly alien to me, not from a lack of refinement, but from a total personal disinterest. Thus my word choice.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having not had horsemeat myself, I can only inquire with one who has: they found it to taste like bland but tender red meat.  So, use mild reds for pairing like you would for beef tenderloin:

- Cabernet Sauvigonon
- Pinot Noir
- Lighter-bodied Shiraz/Syrah

Comment: Bland is not an adjective I would really use for horse meat... it has a quite easy-to-spot sweet taste.

Comment: @Nico: I'm just going on what I heard... are the wine pairings still reasonable?

Comment: I'd have said the same, more or less: red meat, red wine. At any rate, some will combine an aged white where they'd use a young red (it's a fashion thing).

Comment: @BaffledCook, when you say that's a fashion thing, am I right that you're saying there's really no reason beyond that? Or is there actually some affinity between an aged white and a young red in terms of flavor/taste that undergirds such a fashion? (I'm *really* not an oenophile, and I enjoy all of this feedback.)

Comment: @BobMcGee: yes I think the wines are fine, a Cabernet Sauvignon would probably be my first choice I guess. I was just surprised to read horse meat is *bland*!

Comment: @EdDean, the reason is that aged white wines have more flavor than ordinary white wines and can indeed combine with red meat. However, combining white wines with red meat is a recent thing and might blow over, therefore fashion.

Comment: @BaffledCook, ah I see. Danke!